Recursive piecewise integral formula
I have the recursive formula for the integral $1/(x^2+a^2)^n$, which is, in fact, the one that Ng Chung Tak provides in this link. My problem is that when finding a specific integral, for the case $n=2$, I get stuck at the value of $I_1$, since when replacing $n=1$ in the recursive formula I end up finding a zero in the denominator.
In the last part I get a zero in the denominator. Am I making a mistake or, if not, 'how do I proceed?


When $n = 1$, you do not use the recursion formula.  Instead, you just observe $$I_1 = \int \frac{dx}{x^2 + a^2} = \frac{1}{a} \arctan \frac{x}{a} + C.$$  When $n = 2$, the recursion formula yields
$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^2} &= \frac{x}{2a^2(2-1)(x^2+a^2)} + \frac{2(2)-3}{2a^2(2-1)} \int \frac{dx}{x^2+a^2} \\
&= \frac{x}{2a^2(x^2+a^2)} + \frac{1}{2a^3} \arctan \frac{x}{a} + C.
\end{align}$$
